# How to check response in s3 client using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I want to transfer folder to s3 Aws, in localhost everuthing ok, but error shows on server(gitlab ci):

> Error parsing response for PutObject: AWS parsing error: Error parsing XML: String could not be parsed as XML.

My code:

```
$manager = new Transfer($client, $source, $dest); 
$manager->transfer();
```

I tried guzzle history middleware, but no luck:

```
$container = [];
$history = Middleware::history($container); 
$stack = HandlerStack::create(); // Add the history middleware to the handler stack. 
$stack->push($history); 
echo count($container); // 0
```

Comment: Refer [URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-transfer.html)

Comment: @Gunaseelan Yes, I do like that

Comment: debug = true helped, it shows me that it can't put file 301 http code. So I said to admins and waiting them